# Show check mark in selected item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, getview

I am trying to create a language selecting screen. I have a ListView and I am using custom adapter class. Upon selecting an item, I want to show a tick mark in the item. My ListView have a TextView` and an ImageView. How to achieve it?

Here is what I have tried already.

Any answer and suggestions are appreciated, Thanks in advance

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] languages ;
        Context mContext;
        boolean isChecked = false;
    
        public customAdapter(String[] languages, Context  
        mContext){
            this.languages = languages;
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return languages.length;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,              
            ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)                  
            mContext.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView=                                               
            inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.content_lang_list,parent,false);
    
            TextView lang_text = (TextView)                                    
            rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_select_lang);
            final ImageView image_tick = (ImageView)                    
            rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_tick);
    
            lang_text.setText(languages[position]);
            image_tick.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checked);
    
            return rowView;
    
        }




    public class ChangeLang extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private ListView languageList;
        String[] languages = {"English","Portuguese","Arabic"};
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cahnge_lang);
    
            languageList = (ListView)
            findViewById(R.id.language_list);
            final customAdapter mAdapter = new customAdapter(
            languages,this);
            languageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    
            languageList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int position, long id) {
                    String selected = ((TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.text_select_lang))
                    .getText().toString();
                    Object itemObject =parent.getAdapter()
                    .getItem(position);
                    LanguageSelect selectedLang =                          
                    (LanguageSelect)itemObject;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a language selection screen, I assume you need to select only one item at a time.  You have already added a boolean member `isChecked;` but doesn't seems to be used anywhere.

## Step 1:

What you need here is an int member - say, `selectedItemPosition` whose initial value set as -1. 
In other words, replace

```
boolean isChecked = false;
```

with

```
int selectedItemPosition = -1;
```

## Step 2:

Add this to `onItemClick()`

```
selectedItemPosition = ((selectedItemPosition!=position)?position:-1);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

## Step 3:

Add this to your `getView()`

```
image_tick.setVisibility((selectedItemPosition=position)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
```

## Few tips:

- While using `ListViews`, [follow view holder pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling#ViewHolder) to optimize performance.
- Use `convertView`s to recycle views.
- You can replace `image_tick.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checked);` with `android:src="R.drawable.ic_checked"` in XML.

Comment: what about this      ? languageList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_select_lang)).getText().toString();
                Object itemObject = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                LanguageSelect selectedLang = (LanguageSelect)itemObject;



            }
        });

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: step 2 onItemClick i dont understand, where i use main activity or adapter class.in main activty what to do

Comment: I mean the `onItemClick()` method of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. You have already set it inside `OnCreate()`

Comment: int isChecked = -1;        
image_tick.setVisibility((selectedItemPosition=position)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);                                                                      when i set this  showing incompatiable types.Required boolean, Found int

Comment: I think you have typed it wrongly. Try copy and pasting

Comment: int selectedItemPosition = -1;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_lang_list,parent,false);
        TextView lang_text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_select_lang);
        ImageView image_tick = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_tick);
        lang_text.setText(languages[position]);
        image_tick.setVisibility((selectedItemPosition=position)?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
        return rowView;
    }

Comment: look at my comment above how i set and say whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in the image item that was clicked!  ie:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_lang_list,parent,false);

    TextView lang_text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_select_lang);
    final ImageView image_tick = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_tick);

    lang_text.setText(languages[position]);
    image_tick.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checked);
    image_tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Show image
    return rowView;

}
```

Comment: it will be gone when scrolling.

Comment: Which kind of trouble? Can you post your `xml` to check out it?

Comment: when i click list item i want to show the tick image